# Блоки в html не уменьшается до 0%

Tags: javascript, html, css, style, blocks

Почему когда блоку задаёшь высоту 0% или же px они не уменьшается до 0 почему так происходит? И как это сделать или реализовать по другому.

Comment: Покажите тестовый пример...

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: На это может повлиять пропорция `padding` и ей подобные, также `min-height` и стили которые вы можете случайно задать не тому элементу, много факторов есть.

Answer (score 2):

## Факторы

### Фактор 1

Свойство `padding` и ему подобные

Такие свойства как `padding`, `padding-bottom`, `padding-top` не зависят от свойства `height`, а само оно увеличивает размер элемента, вот пример:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  height: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Фактор 2

Свойство `min-height` указывает минимальную высоту и не зависимо от `height` всё равно будет указывать высоту элемента. (Если она меньше чем высота которую вы указываете в `height`)

Пример с `min-height`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  height: 0;
  min-height: 25px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Фактор 3

Вы случайно могли указать селектор который, также подходит под элемент, который вы создали.

Вот пример:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  height: 0;
  background: red;
}

body > div {
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Фактор 4

Атрибут `controls`, он указывает, будет ли у элемента `<video>` показываться управление, вот пример (Не знаю как у вас, а у меня управление видно, оно, собственно говоря, занимает какую-то высоту экрана):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  height: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<video controls=""></video>
```

### Фактор 5

Инлайн-стили, если вы попытались указать в своих CSS стилях пропорции различные от инлайн-стилей, допустим поменять `height: 25px;` на `hieght: 0px`, то тогда так не выйдет, т.к. инлайн-стили всегда по приоритету выше чем обычные CSS стили, для того чтобы обойти инлайн-стили, можно дописать в конце значения пропорции  `!important` и тогда она станет приоритетнее чем ваш инлайн-стиль, но точно также может быть указанно в инлайн-стилях (в смысле `!important`), так что будьте осторожны. Вот пример:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  height: 0;
  background: red;
}

/* Решение */

div {
  height: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 25px;"></div>
```

## Итог

Таких факторов может быть ещё больше, без конкретного кода не понятно, но я вроде бы озвучил довольно популярные причины по которой может произойти ваша проблема. Смотрите и изучайте :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете уменьшить значения до нуля и на скриншотах видно, как изменилась высота блока (до изменения высоты) и (после изменения высоты)

Ссылка на скриншоты:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ksd013OyA8_7CEbPjMHC1pLRm-e7sITu?usp=sharing

Comment: ну и также как в комментариях указал NNL993 на это могут повлиять другие css - свойства например такие как(-min -max height)